# Check returned value by res is null

Tags: java, android

this is my code to check if the value of column is not null

`if(!res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")).trim().equals("")){`

but I get this:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference

What is the proper way to check if value return by res is empty

Comment: looks like res is null in if-statement. please provide some more code

Comment: Try this if(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")) != null && !res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")).trim().equals(""))

Comment: @Raghavendra this one is return error `!res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")).trim(‌​).equals("")` but first one is ok can you provide it as answer so i can close the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if(res != null){
    if(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")) != null && !res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")).trim(‌​).equals("")) 

//your stuff

}
```

Comment: i am getting error if i include this `&& !res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")).trim(‌​).equals("")` any idea?

Comment: Looks like res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")) is null so u need to do a null check before accessing trim() method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid"))!=null){
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the value of something which may be null, which will throw a Null object reference. to fix this you must check if the `String` is `null`.

```
if (res != null) {
     String str = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid"));
    if(str != null) {
       // Perform action
    } else {
      // String is null so recover (use placeholder, try again etc)
    }
}
```

alternativley you can do it in one if statement but I find the above more readable.

```
if (res != null) {
    if( res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")) != null &&
        res.getString(!res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")).trim().equals("")) {
        //Safe to use String
    }
}
```

Comment: What if res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")) itself null?

Comment: i've removed the call to Trim but it didn't throw the exception in Op's code. i feel your downvote is misplaced here.

Comment: What if `res` itself is null?

Comment: @OlarAndrei you could ask the same in any of the answers, but a valid point all the same

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways for it:

**First is checking if res exists (best approach)**

```
if(res.getIdentifier(myStringName) != 0){
  //do stuff
}
```

Because if it returns 0 it means it doesn't exists.

**Second way is checking if string is null**

```
String myRes = res.getString(myStringName);
if(myRes != null && !myRes.trim().equals("")){
  //do stuff 
}
```

Your problem was that you were not checking if the `String` result was `null`

Hope this helps